# How can I update all input fields with one button and make a button to delete items individually?

Tags: php, cart

I've been making a shopping cart where I display the products with a delete button for each product and an update button to update all the quantity fields.
The problem is that when I have managed to make update button work the delete button delete the last product not the one that I wanted to.
I know is a problem with the form but i do not know how to resolve it.

```
   $i = 0;
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
   //loop product info 

   echo'<form action="" method="POST">
        <input class="inp" type="hidden" name="h_order" value="'.$row['order_id'].'"/>
        <input class="inp" type="hidden" name="order[]" value="'.$row['order_id'].'"/>
        <input class="inp" style="width:30px;" type="text" name="';
        echo 'quantity[$row['order_id']]'; 
        echo 'value="'.$row['quantity'].'" autocomplete="off"/>';
if($i == 0){
echo'<table>';
}
   echo '<td>'.$total.'</td>    
    <td>
        <center>        
            <button class="action red" type="submit" name="delete" title="Delete">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x"></i>
            </button>
        </center>
    </td>   
    </tr>';
    $i++;
}
 echo '<tr>
    <td colspan="6">
        <button class="button action blue" style="float:right;" type="submit" name="update" title="Update quantity">
            <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-lg"></i>
                <a>Update cart</a>
        </button>
    </td>
 </tr>  
</table>
</form>';
```

Comment: Well, it certainly wouldn't hurt if you could fix trivial mistakes in your code first: **I strongly suggest using valid markup**. Even though most browsers will render it quite correctly, you can't place `<form>` elements inside `<table>` directly. Also, you mix PHP and HTML too much, making sustainable development on your project ever-increasingly difficult in the near-future.

Comment: I tried to fix what you said, it is better?

Comment: He's saying the easiest way to do this is to use templates where the predominant code is HTML, and php is used to pass in the dynamic parts, whereas here you're using PHP to build all of the html

Comment: But then how i would display products from loop inside the html code?

Comment: Really?No one can help me?